# Conda Dependencies in Apache Beam Pipeline

Tags: python, conda, apache-beam

Beam's documentation lays out how to supply remote execution runners with dependencies [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/); however, PyPI seems to be the only built package manager supported.  Is it possible to specify conda dependencies/a conda environment file to install and execute from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not yet possible. Beam is, however, moving to a framework where one can supply the set of dependencies via a docker image, in which case one can install the required dependencies however one may want (including via conda).

Comment: Where would I find details about this efforts to support docker image execution?